# Rails 4 + Capistrano: Deploy failing with bundle exit status: 127

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to deploy using capistrano. `staging deploy:check` works fine. But now when I do `staging deploy`, it doesn't work. It looks like it's failing on `-L` (?? Don't know what that is). Is there any way to make it more verbose?

```
Nets-Mac-Pro:mysite emai$ be cap staging deploy --trace
** Invoke staging (first_time)
** Execute staging
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke bundler:map_bins (first_time)
** Execute bundler:map_bins
** Invoke deploy (first_time)
** Execute deploy
** Invoke deploy:starting (first_time)
** Execute deploy:starting
** Invoke deploy:check (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check
** Invoke git:check (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper (first_time)
** Execute git:wrapper
INFO[ffff7fb7] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/mysite-staging/ on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[ffff7fb7] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/mysite-staging/
INFO[ffff7fb7] Finished in 1.168 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUGUploading /tmp/mysite-staging/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
INFOUploading /tmp/mysite-staging/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
INFO[add049a4] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/mysite-staging/git-ssh.sh on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[add049a4] Command: /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/mysite-staging/git-ssh.sh
INFO[add049a4] Finished in 0.042 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Execute git:check
DEBUG[93984945] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote -h git@github.com:nettheory/mysite.git on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[93984945] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/mysite-staging/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote -h git@github.com:nettheory/mysite.git )
DEBUG[93984945]     a63439b163c1b79e58da9335b75983caf28afe0a
DEBUG[93984945]         
DEBUG[93984945]     refs/heads/master
DEBUG[93984945]     
DEBUG[93984945] Finished in 0.190 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:check:directories (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:directories
INFO[f8758c25] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[f8758c25] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases
INFO[f8758c25] Finished in 0.046 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:check:linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:linked_dirs
INFO[8ff200a0] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/bin /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/log /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/tmp/pids /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/tmp/cache /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/tmp/sockets /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/vendor/bundle /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/public/system on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[8ff200a0] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/bin /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/log /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/tmp/pids /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/tmp/cache /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/tmp/sockets /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/vendor/bundle /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/public/system
INFO[8ff200a0] Finished in 0.052 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:check:make_linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:make_linked_dirs
** Invoke deploy:check:linked_files (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:linked_files
** Invoke deploy:set_previous_revision (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_previous_revision
DEBUG[41227397] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/current/REVISION ] on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[41227397] Command: [ -f /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/current/REVISION ]
DEBUG[41227397] Finished in 0.046 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
** Invoke deploy:started (first_time)
** Execute deploy:started
** Invoke deploy:updating (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:new_release_path (first_time)
** Execute deploy:new_release_path
** Execute deploy:updating
** Invoke git:create_release (first_time)
** Invoke git:update (first_time)
** Invoke git:clone (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper 
** Execute git:clone
DEBUG[32dfac80] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/repo/HEAD ] on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[32dfac80] Command: [ -f /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/repo/HEAD ]
DEBUG[32dfac80] Finished in 0.058 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFOThe repository mirror is at /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/repo
** Execute git:update
DEBUG[ca99ad18] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/usr/local/www/mysite-staging/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[ca99ad18] Command: if test ! -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/usr/local/www/mysite-staging/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG[ca99ad18] Finished in 0.047 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[daa4e97a] Running /usr/bin/env git remote update on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[daa4e97a] Command: cd /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/repo && ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/mysite-staging/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git remote update )
DEBUG[daa4e97a]     Fetching origin
DEBUG[daa4e97a]     
INFO[daa4e97a] Finished in 0.208 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Execute git:create_release
DEBUG[2cc58d69] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/usr/local/www/mysite-staging/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[2cc58d69] Command: if test ! -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/usr/local/www/mysite-staging/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG[2cc58d69] Finished in 0.046 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[bb764d86] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830 on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[bb764d86] Command: cd /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/repo && ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/mysite-staging/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830 )
INFO[bb764d86] Finished in 0.048 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[660eaf93] Running /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -C /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830 on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[660eaf93] Command: cd /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/repo && ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/mysite-staging/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -C /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830 )
INFO[660eaf93] Finished in 0.094 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:set_current_revision (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_current_revision
** Invoke git:set_current_revision (first_time)
** Execute git:set_current_revision
DEBUG[fa29353b] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/usr/local/www/mysite-staging/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[fa29353b] Command: if test ! -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/usr/local/www/mysite-staging/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG[fa29353b] Finished in 0.044 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG[6ef35cbf] Running /usr/bin/env git rev-parse --short master on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[6ef35cbf] Command: cd /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/repo && ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/mysite-staging/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git rev-parse --short master )
DEBUG[6ef35cbf]     a63439b
DEBUG[6ef35cbf]     
DEBUG[6ef35cbf] Finished in 0.055 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG[7fd07be7] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830; then echo "Directory does not exist '/usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830'" 1>&2; false; fi on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[7fd07be7] Command: if test ! -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830; then echo "Directory does not exist '/usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG[7fd07be7] Finished in 0.042 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[8c5e739b] Running /usr/bin/env echo "a63439b" >> REVISION on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[8c5e739b] Command: cd /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830 && /usr/bin/env echo "a63439b" >> REVISION
INFO[8c5e739b] Finished in 0.045 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:symlink:shared (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:shared
** Invoke deploy:symlink:linked_files (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:linked_files
** Invoke deploy:symlink:linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:linked_dirs
INFO[fba36df0] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830 /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830 /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/vendor /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/public on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[fba36df0] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830 /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830 /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/vendor /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/public
INFO[fba36df0] Finished in 0.073 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG[fba36df0]     mkdir: created directory ‘/usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp’
INFO[fba36df0] Finished in 0.073 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG[3a08f40c] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/bin ] on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[3a08f40c] Command: [ -L /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/bin ]
DEBUG[3a08f40c] Finished in 0.057 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG[da8d0753] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/bin ] on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[da8d0753] Command: [ -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/bin ]
DEBUG[da8d0753] Finished in 0.050 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[a697eb88] Running /usr/bin/env rm -rf /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/bin on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[a697eb88] Command: /usr/bin/env rm -rf /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/bin
INFO[a697eb88] Finished in 0.065 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[906ae4c7] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/bin /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/bin on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[906ae4c7] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/bin /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/bin
INFO[906ae4c7] Finished in 0.047 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG[c24d208a] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/log ] on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[c24d208a] Command: [ -L /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/log ]
DEBUG[c24d208a] Finished in 0.045 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG[07bc9474] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/log ] on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[07bc9474] Command: [ -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/log ]
DEBUG[07bc9474] Finished in 0.046 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[e686949b] Running /usr/bin/env rm -rf /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/log on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[e686949b] Command: /usr/bin/env rm -rf /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/log
INFO[e686949b] Finished in 0.048 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[75d4cfdf] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/log /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/log on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[75d4cfdf] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/log /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/log
INFO[75d4cfdf] Finished in 0.059 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG[63748a27] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp/pids ] on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[63748a27] Command: [ -L /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp/pids ]
DEBUG[63748a27] Finished in 0.044 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG[779ad81c] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp/pids ] on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[779ad81c] Command: [ -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp/pids ]
DEBUG[779ad81c] Finished in 0.044 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
INFO[a02509b8] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/tmp/pids /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp/pids on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[a02509b8] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/tmp/pids /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp/pids
INFO[a02509b8] Finished in 0.054 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG[8a109593] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp/cache ] on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[8a109593] Command: [ -L /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp/cache ]
DEBUG[8a109593] Finished in 0.046 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG[5adb460c] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp/cache ] on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[5adb460c] Command: [ -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp/cache ]
DEBUG[5adb460c] Finished in 0.041 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
INFO[daf9b1c5] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/tmp/cache /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp/cache on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[daf9b1c5] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/tmp/cache /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp/cache
INFO[daf9b1c5] Finished in 0.045 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG[2b6dd050] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp/sockets ] on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[2b6dd050] Command: [ -L /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp/sockets ]
DEBUG[2b6dd050] Finished in 0.042 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG[58893ed8] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp/sockets ] on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[58893ed8] Command: [ -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp/sockets ]
DEBUG[58893ed8] Finished in 0.045 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
INFO[ffb6bc4d] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/tmp/sockets /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp/sockets on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[ffb6bc4d] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/tmp/sockets /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/tmp/sockets
INFO[ffb6bc4d] Finished in 0.051 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG[106c78c5] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/vendor/bundle ] on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[106c78c5] Command: [ -L /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/vendor/bundle ]
DEBUG[106c78c5] Finished in 0.043 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG[3704aab3] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/vendor/bundle ] on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[3704aab3] Command: [ -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/vendor/bundle ]
DEBUG[3704aab3] Finished in 0.044 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
INFO[1cda2e52] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/vendor/bundle /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/vendor/bundle on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[1cda2e52] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/vendor/bundle /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/vendor/bundle
INFO[1cda2e52] Finished in 0.044 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG[f1212c44] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/public/system ] on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[f1212c44] Command: [ -L /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/public/system ]
DEBUG[f1212c44] Finished in 0.043 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG[cab81996] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/public/system ] on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[cab81996] Command: [ -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/public/system ]
DEBUG[cab81996] Finished in 0.047 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
INFO[48dcef21] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/public/system /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/public/system on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[48dcef21] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/public/system /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830/public/system
INFO[48dcef21] Finished in 0.042 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:updated (first_time)
** Invoke bundler:install (first_time)
** Execute bundler:install
DEBUG[e736990c] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830; then echo "Directory does not exist '/usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830'" 1>&2; false; fi on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[e736990c] Command: if test ! -d /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830; then echo "Directory does not exist '/usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG[e736990c] Finished in 0.043 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[cb19bf3b] Running /usr/bin/env bundle install --binstubs /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/bin --path /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[cb19bf3b] Command: cd /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/releases/20140718204830 && /usr/bin/env bundle install --binstubs /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/bin --path /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host mysite-staging.nettheory.com: bundle exit status: 127
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: Nothing written
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/command.rb:97:in `exit_status='
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:148:in `block (5 levels) in _execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `call'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `do_request'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:561:in `channel_request'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:170:in `block (3 levels) in _execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `call'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `do_open_confirmation'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:545:in `channel_open_confirmation'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:172:in `block (2 levels) in _execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:186:in `with_ssh'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:131:in `block in _execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `tap'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `_execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/capistrano-bundler-1.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/bundler.cap:30:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:85:in `with'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/capistrano-bundler-1.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/bundler.cap:22:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:77:in `within'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/capistrano-bundler-1.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/bundler.cap:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 127
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: Nothing written
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/command.rb:97:in `exit_status='
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:148:in `block (5 levels) in _execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `call'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `do_request'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:561:in `channel_request'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:170:in `block (3 levels) in _execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `call'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `do_open_confirmation'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:545:in `channel_open_confirmation'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:172:in `block (2 levels) in _execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:186:in `with_ssh'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:131:in `block in _execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `tap'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `_execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/capistrano-bundler-1.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/bundler.cap:30:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:85:in `with'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/capistrano-bundler-1.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/bundler.cap:22:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:77:in `within'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/capistrano-bundler-1.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/bundler.cap:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host mysite-staging.nettheory.com: bundle exit status: 127
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: Nothing written
>
** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
** Execute deploy:failed
Nets-Mac-Pro:mysite emai$
```

Comment: I was missing bundler. `sudo gem install bundler` worked!

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get install bundler`

Worked for me!